# JavaFX Add data to Column's instead of row

Tags: javafx, tableview

Good day,

I have a fixed number of columns in TableView, however I need to populate column by column, not row by row, as one column data depends on the previous one. Is there an example of such thing? I have searched for such way, but unfortunately. Hope I made it understandable.

Comment: Questions asking to find a tutorial are off topic, but since I had a nice day: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm (Just initializing properties with `null` should create a table with empty cells, then iterate through the items and set the values of the property for the first column, iterate through them again and set the values for the second column, ect.)

Answer (score 1):

Since nobody provided me an example, and the comment was not very helpful I manage to solve my problem in the following way (in my case one column result depends on the previous one and the number of elements can be different as well as the number of columns are predefined)

Simple example:

We have an object:

```
public class Cars{
private String name;
private String company;
private String year;
public Cars(String name,String company,String year){
   this.name=name;
   this.company=company;
   this.year=year;
}
 public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name= name;
    }

    public String getCompany() {
        return company;
    }

    public void setCompany(String company) {
        this.company= company;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year= year;
    }
}
```

Then we have our table:

```
public TableView createTable() {
        TableView<Cars> table = new TableView<>();

    TableColumn<Cars, String> nameyColumn = new TableColumn("Name");
    nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("name"));

    TableColumn<Cars, String> companyColumn = new TableColumn<>("Company");
    companyColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("company"));

    TableColumn<Cars, String> yearColumn = new TableColumn<>("Year");
    yearColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("year"));

    table.setItems(makeCars());
    table.getColumns().addAll(nameColumn, companyColumn, yearColumn);
    return table;
}
```

Afterwards we generate the information that we want to put into the table and put all the information into, in this case a String Array. So if we have 3 String arrays we can make an ArrayListlist of arrays and populate it with information.

However, the sizes of the String arrays inside the ArrayList have to be predefined, so that you would not get a NullPointException where the at one point you have a car's name and you dont have a year it will be set to an empty automatically, as an empty predefined String array contains null as elements automatically. So in my case I know the max size that one array can be and set all of them to the same size.

And afterwards I just loop through the ArrayList of String Arrays and create objects which I add to the ObservableList ( might be a better way of doing it but I did it this way):

```
private ObservableList<Cars> makeCars() {
        ObservableList<Cars> madeList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        ArrayList<String[]>arrayOfArrays=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<maxRow;i++){
            madeList.add(new Cars(arrayOfArrays.get(0)[i],arrayOfArrays.get(1)[i],
                    arrayOfArrays.get(2)[i]));
        }

        return madeList;
    }
```

Hope this will helpful to somebody, if there is a better way and I am overdoing it please share.